# Retrieving values from basicdblist Mongo

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

```
{
DB db = Helper.connectingMonggo();
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", "123");
DBCollection table = new db.getCollection("prodDetail");
DBCursor cursor = table.find(query); --// cursor has only one record (size =1)

while(cursor.hasNext()){
  DBObject obj = cursor.next();
  List<String> upcs = new ArrayList<>();
  BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList) obj.get("prodList"); --//here prodList size also 1 always
  DBObject obj1 = (DBObject) list.get(0);
  BasicDBList detailsList = (BasicDBList) obj1.get("pDetailsList");

 for(Object obj2 : detailsList){
   JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject(JSON.serialize(obj2));
   ups.add(obj3.get("upcStatus").toString());
 } } }
```

I am getting the list array with upcStatus but, is it proper way to write?

Comment: The way you have the code is a way of getting the result. You can also use an aggregation query to get the output _without_ the cursor and for-loop logic. Also you can use the newer APIs of the [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) - see Reference ->Tutorials / Examples..

Answer (score 0):

This is an aggregation query using the MongoDB Java driver v3.12 and MongoDB v4.2. Note the result is returned using a single query and no additional code. This is useful as the query is entirely run on the server and the result is returned to your Java application.

```
try(MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create()) {
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("testCollection");
    List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("_id", 123)),
        Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(
            Projections.excludeId(), 
                Projections.computed("upcStatus", Filters.eq("$arrayElemAt", 
                    Arrays.asList("$prodList.pDetailsList.upcStatus", 0L))
                )
        ))
    );
    
    Document doc = coll.aggregate(pipeline).first();
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());    // prints the array of upcStatus field values
}
```

The classes used in the code are defined as following classes or in packages: `org.bson.Document`, `org.bson.conversions.Bson`, `com.mongodb.client.model.*` and `com.mongodb.client.*`.

Also, note the `try` statement-block opens the connection to the server and closes automatically at the end of the try-block.

Comment: I updated my question with dbconnection method that I used. I think I used the old approach, I didn't used MongoClients.create() to connect to mongodb. Can you please let me know how to use MongoClients.create() to connect to mongo in my case
Thank you.

Comment: The following link has both the _old_ and _new_ way of connecting: [Connect to MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/) using Java driver.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working now, but I am getting one product upcStatus only. I have more than one product (pID's).. Updated the JSON response now (sorry my bad .. I didn't gave properly earlier)... Getting ["Available", "Not Availabe"] only but I want all the 4 like ["Available", "Not Availabe", "Available", "Not Available"]

Comment: You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) aggregation stage on the array fields, and then use projection to get the specified values.

Comment: I tried but no luck .. may be I am not used $unwind properly, I tried adding $unwind to coll like coll.aggreagate({$unwind : "$upcStatus"}) .. Can you please give me the code for $unwind ... thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to unwind the outer array `prodList` and then unwind the inner array `pDetailsList`, and verify what output is. Then use projection to get the required values.